# How to add md-Tooltip within md-fab Toolbar buttons in angular material design :

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ggRQqR

I am trying to add tooltips to my buttons which are inside a fab toolbar.

However, the tooltips are overlapping each other & i am not getting the functionality as expected.

The tooltips should only show when I am hovering over the exact button.

I have added two screen shots which show the wierd behavior.

[image]

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" class="tooltipdemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp">

     <md-fab-toolbar class="md-fab md-accent md-fab-bottom-right">
        <md-fab-trigger class="align-with-text">
            <md-button aria-label="menu" class="md-fab md-primary">
                <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/ic_insert_drive_file_24px.svg"></md-icon>
                <md-tooltip>Options</md-tooltip>
            </md-button>
        </md-fab-trigger>
        <md-toolbar>
            <md-fab-actions class="md-toolbar-tools">
                <md-button aria-label="Save" class="md-icon-button" ng-click="vm.update()" ng-disabled="vm.loading || vm.data.length==0" >
                    <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/ic_photo_24px.svg" style="width: 24px; height: 24px;"></md-icon>
                    <md-tooltip>Save</md-tooltip>
                </md-button>
                <md-button aria-label="Reset" class="md-icon-button"  >
                   <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/ic_photo_24px.svg" style="width: 24px; height: 24px; "></md-icon> <md-tooltip>Refresh</md-tooltip>
                </md-button>

            </md-fab-actions>
        </md-toolbar>
    </md-fab-toolbar>

</div>
```

Comment: Sadly this is a bug from angular material and idk if it has been fixed yet, it is a positioning problem and there is no known workaround [link](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/5124)

Answer (score 5):

I have a way to fix it. But it is not perfect solution. After checking the Angular-Material's code I found that their tooltip gets initialised based on parent's `pointer-events` css properties, which makes sure the parent has pointer events and not set to `none`.

I was having the same problem, So I fixed it by adding pointer events to the menu's icon and removing it after the page has loaded.

[CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/rahul-sagore/pen/LzbLPN)

#### Steps to fix:

1) Add this css code into your css file (Make sure it override existing css)

```
md-fab-toolbar md-toolbar.pevents__initial {
  pointer-events: initial;
}
```

2) Add `pevents__initial` class to the `md-toolbar` element, which is inside `md-fab-toolbar`:

```
<md-toolbar class='pevents__initial'>
    <md-fab-actions class="md-toolbar-tools">
    </md-fab-actions>
</md-toolbar>
```

3) Add this javascript code to remove `pevents__initial` class from above html (Other wise your menu will not work):

```
setTimeout(function() {
   $('.pevents__initial').removeClass('pevents__initial');
}, 1000);
```

This is just a hack to make tooltip work inside fab toolbar. Need to read the official code more to find more better solution. But this works for me right now.